# Show that $\binom{n+1}{r} = \binom{n}{r} +\binom{n}{r-1}$ for $1 ≤ r ≤ n$.

Tags: combinations, binomial-coefficients, factorial

I've found many ways of proving $\binom{n}{r} = \binom{n-1}{r} +\binom{n-1}{r-1}$ However I can't find any for proving that:

$$\binom{n+1}{r} = \binom{n}{r} +\binom{n}{r-1}\;\text{ for }1 ≤ r ≤ n.$$

When I expand the equation it comes out to this:

$$\frac{(n+1)!}{(n-r+1)!r!}= \frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}+\frac{n!}{(n-(r-1))!(r-1)!}$$

I'm not sure where to go from here.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi and welcome! If you look better at your formulas, you may notice that they are the same; the first one you know the proof is valid for $1\leq r\leq n$ and you can choose $n$ as you want. Then if you choose $n = n'+1$ you obtain the second formula

Comment: Hint: use common denominator

Comment: Please use `\binom{n}{r}` $\binom nr$ instead of $C(n,r)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$C(n, r) + C(n, r − 1)=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}+\frac{n!}{(n-r+1)!(r-1)!}=\frac{n!(n-r+1)+n!r}{(n-r+1)!r!}=\frac{(n+1)!}{(n-r+1)!r!}=C(n + 1, r) $$

Comment: Could you please show how you got from:
$\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}+\frac{n!}{(n-r+1)!(r-1)!}=\frac{n!(n-r+1)+n!r}{(n-r+1)!r!}$
I don't understand that step

Comment: Note: $(n-r+1)!=(n-r)!(n-r+1)$ and $r!=(r-1)!r$

Comment: So then how did you get rid of the $r$ to get to $(n+1)!$

Comment: at numerator factoring $n!$ : $n!(n-r+1+r)=n!(n+1)=(n+1)!$

Comment: Ah I see thx for the great answer

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Just make the mapping $n \mapsto n+1$ in your original identity. Or, if that's a bit too hard to understand, simply let $n=k+1$. The desired form appears immediately.

Put another way, the two identities are equivalent.

Comment: I don't understand is there some way to expand/simplify the equations

Comment: Probably, but why overcomplicate matters like that? The algebra involved in identities like these is often cumbersome.

Comment: If I change n -> n+1 doesnt that make the left side have n+2 and that just brings up more problems

Comment: If you let $n=k+1$ as suggested, then you get

$$C(k+1,r) = C((k+1)-1,r) + C((k+1)-1,r-1)$$

which simplifies to

$$C(k+1,r) = C(k,r) + C(k,r-1)$$

From there, it's ultimately a dummy variable, so you can still claim

$$C(n+1,r) = C(n,r) + C(n,r-1)$$

Comment: However, in the question, the left side starts off as $C(n+1, r)$ so changing it to $k+1$ would make it $C(k+2, r)$ wouldn't it?

Comment: You start from the original/given identity, $C(n,r) = C(n-1,r) + C(n-1,r-1)$.

Comment: The given identity is $C(n+1,r)=C(n,r)+C(n,r−1)$ for $1≤r≤n.$
the other one is just what I found when I was researching

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106129/discussion-between-betacrasher-and-eevee-trainer).

Answer (score 0):

A selection of $r$ from $n+1$ items in a line either includes the first item and $r-1$ from the remaining $n$, or does not include the first item and all $r$ are from the rest.   Therefore:
$$\binom {n+1}{r}=\binom{1}{1}\binom{n}{r-1}+\binom 10\binom nr$$